# Tosca: searching for CPs within test step values

Tags: tosca

I'm trying to find a way to search for the usages of Test Configuration Parameters within test steps.

For example, I would like to look up the string "{CP[param]}" within a library or folder and end up on the step containing it.

I've had a look at the [official examples for searching for a Test Step value](https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1400/en/content/tosca_commander/tql_examples.htm#TestStepValue), and thought I could simply swap that "motorcycle" with my CP, BUT actually I cannot even make it work with a simple value such as "True". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer by contacting Tricentis Support. Here is what they told me. I've already tested it and it works.

To find the test step whose test step value uses a TCP, you can use the below TQL query:

```
=>RETURN SUBPARTS:XTestStep=>SUBPARTS:XTestStepValue[Value=?"CP"]
```

In case you want to find the specific TestStep value, you can use:

```
=>SUBPARTS:XTestStepValue[Value=?"CP"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This query should find all values that use the specified config param:

```
=>SUBPARTS:TestCase=> return Items=>TestStepValues[Value =i? "{CP[param]}"]
```

The reason the query that you found doesn't work is that you can't use it for searches across TestCases. It only works if the root of the search is set on or within a TestCase. By first searching for all TestCases `(=>SUBPARTS:TestCase)` and then selecting all the items inside `(=>Items)` you can also use it to search across multiple TestCases.

"return" next to Items indicates that the target of the search is the TestStep and not the last element in the query. If you remove it the query will return TestStepValues.

`"=i?"` indicates a contains case insensitive query.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a go next week!

Comment: Hi, I cannot make it work. And here again even for a simple string (like "Motorcycle") I get "could not find any object"... This part works: '=>SUBPARTS:TestCase=> return Items=>TestStepValues', and it returns all TestStepValues. but as soon as I add the [Value... ] part then it does not find anything.